# What are some applications of linear approximation in the real world?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education, applications

What are examples you can give to Calculus I high school students?

[Here is a link to show the level linear approximations will be taught.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LinearApproximations.aspx)

I've found some applications by a simple google search. Mostly, they deal with physics, and it seems that the idea is to make a function easier to deal with since the linear approximation is so close to the actual value.

I have a thermal expansion problem I used last year: $\frac{dP}{dT} = kP$ where  $P = 15$cm when $T = 25℃$, and they needed to find the change in length of the cable when $T = 28℃$.
Also, $k = 1.7 × 10^{−5}℃^{−1}$.

Mostly, I am asking this question to see if some of you have better examples and/or explanations. I can keep searching for more examples, but I am not very familiar with physics and know that I probably won't pick the best example to illustrate how linear approximation can be useful.

Comment: You can easily derive most rules of differential calculus by replacing $f(x + \Delta x)$ with its linear approximation $f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x$. Also, arguably the main reason that so many great mathematical models (in physics or otherwise) are linear is that a nonlinear relationship such as $y'(t) = f(y(t))$ can be approximated as $y'(t) = f(y(t_0)) +f'(y(t_0))(y(t) - y(t_0))$. For example, Hooke's law and Newton's law of cooling are clear examples of this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

*What are some applications of linear approximation in the real world?*

I present below a compilation of possibilities. You can find more applications and more details in the mentioned books (as well as in similar books).

- **Numerical estimation**

> Exemple ([Stewart's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=EBE3vMmGu50C&pg=PA194&dq=%22Use+a+linear+approximation+(or+differentials)+to+estimate+the+given+number.%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimvrntrZPmAhUWHbkGHXSfDW8Q6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Use%20a%20linear%20approximation%20(or%20differentials)%20to%20estimate%20the%20given%20number.%22&f=false)): Use linear approximation to estimate the number  $(1.999)^4$.

*Solution:* Taking $f(x)=x^4$ and $a=2$ in the formula
$$L(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a),$$
we obtain
$$L(x)=32x-48.$$
Therefore,
$$(1.999)^4=f(1.999)\approx L(1.999)=32(1.999)-48=15.968.$$

- **Error propagation**

> Example ([Stewart's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=jBD0yTh64wAC&pg=PA194&dq=The+edge+of+a+cube+was+found+to+be+30+cm+with+a+possible+error+in+measurement+of+0.1+cm.+Use+differentials+to+estimate+the+maximum+possible+error,+relative+error,+and+percentage+error+in+computing+(a)+the+volume+of+the+cube+and+(b)+the+surface+area+of+the+cube.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj98YOysJPmAhWRHbkGHQjwDAAQ6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=The%20edge%20of%20a%20cube%20was%20found%20to%20be%2030%20cm%20with%20a%20possible%20error%20in%20measurement%20of%200.1%20cm.%20Use%20differentials%20to%20estimate%20the%20maximum%20possible%20error%2C%20relative%20error%2C%20and%20percentage%20error%20in%20computing%20(a)%20the%20volume%20of%20the%20cube%20and%20(b)%20the%20surface%20area%20of%20the%20cube.&f=false)): The edge of a cube was found to be $30$ cm with a possible error in measurement of $0.1$ cm. Use linear approximation to estimate the maximum possible error in computing the surface area of the cube.

*Solution:* Taking $f(x)=6x^2$ and $a=30$ in the previous formula, we obtain
$$L(x)=f(30)+f'(30)(x-30)$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Maximum possible error}&=f(30\pm 0.1)-f(30)\\
&\approx L(30\pm 0.1)-f(30)\\
&=f'(30)(\pm 0.1)\\
&=\pm 36\;\text{cm}^2
\end{aligned}$$

- **General approximations**

> Example ([Stewart's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=jBD0yTh64wAC&pg=PA194&dq=Use+differentials+to+estimate+the+amount+of+paint+needed+to+apply+a+coat+of+paint+0.05+cm+thick+to+a+hemispherical+dome+with+diameter+50+m.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj78rjDupPmAhUmIbkGHQoQDFcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Use%20differentials%20to%20estimate%20the%20amount%20of%20paint%20needed%20to%20apply%20a%20coat%20of%20paint%200.05%20cm%20thick%20to%20a%20hemispherical%20dome%20with%20diameter%2050%20m.&f=false)): Use linear approximation to estimate the amount of paint needed to apply a coat of paint $0.05$ cm thick to a hemispherical dome with diameter $50$ m.

*Solution:* Taking $f(x)=\tfrac{2}{3}\pi x^3 $ and $a=25$ in the previous formula, we obtain
$$L(x)=f(50)+f'(25)(x-25)$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
\text{Amount of paint}&=f(25.0005)-f(25)\\
&\approx L(25.0005)-f(25)\\
&=f'(25)(0.0005)\\
&=0.625\pi\\
&\approx 1.96\;\text{m}^3
\end{aligned}$$

- **Applications to Physics**

  1. **Ohm’s Law** ([Larson's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=gR7nGg5_9xcC&pg=PA241&dq=Ohm%E2%80%99s+Law+A+current+of+amperes+passes+through+a+resistor+of+ohms.+Ohm%E2%80%99s+Law+states+that+the+voltage+applied+to+the+resistor+is+If+the+voltage+is+constant,+show+that+the+magnitude+of+the+relative+error+in+caused+by+a+change+in+is+equal+in+magnitude+to+the+relative+error+in&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh1OzIvJPmAhWsHbkGHchECM0Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Ohm%E2%80%99s%20Law%20A%20current%20of%20amperes%20passes%20through%20a%20resistor%20of%20ohms.%20Ohm%E2%80%99s%20Law%20states%20that%20the%20voltage%20applied%20to%20the%20resistor%20is%20If%20the%20voltage%20is%20constant%2C%20show%20that%20the%20magnitude%20of%20the%20relative%20error%20in%20caused%20by%20a%20change%20in%20is%20equal%20in%20magnitude%20to%20the%20relative%20error%20in&f=false)). A current of $I$ amperes passes through a resistor of $R$ ohms. Ohm’s Law states that the voltage $E$ applied to the resistor is $E=IR$. If the voltage is constant, show that the magnitude of the relative error in $R$ caused by a change in $I$ is equal in magnitude to the relative error in $I$.
  2. **Projectile Motion** ([Larson's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=gR7nGg5_9xcC&pg=PA241&dq=Projectile+Motion+The+range+of+a+projectile+is+where+is+the+initial+velocity+in+feet+per+second+and+is+the+angle+of+elevation.+If+feet+per+second+and+is+changed+from+to+use+differentials+to+approximate+the+change+in+the+range.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8zL72vJPmAhX_HbkGHcm0CLAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Projectile%20Motion%20The%20range%20of%20a%20projectile%20is%20where%20is%20the%20initial%20velocity%20in%20feet%20per%20second%20and%20is%20the%20angle%20of%20elevation.%20If%20feet%20per%20second%20and%20is%20changed%20from%20to%20use%20differentials%20to%20approximate%20the%20change%20in%20the%20range.&f=false)). The range of a projectile is $R=\frac{v_0^2}{32}\sin (2\theta)$ where $v_0$ is the initial velocity in feet per second and $\theta$ is the angle of elevation. If $v_0=2200$ feet per second and $\theta$ is changed from $10^\circ$ to $11^\circ$ , use linear approximation to approximate the change in the range.
  3. **Period of a pendulum** ([Anton's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=U2uv84cpJHQC&pg=RA1-PA183&dq=The+time+required+for+one+complete+oscillation+of+a+pendu-+lum+is+called+its+period.+If+L+is+the+length+of+the+pendu-+lum+and+the+oscillation+is+small,+then+the+period+is+given+by+P+%3D+2%CF%80+?+L+/+g,+where+g+is+the+constant+acceleration+due+to+gravity.+Use+differentials+to+show+that+the+percentage+error+in+P+is+approximately+half+the+percentage+error+in+L.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGh7Dzv5PmAhWdEbkGHfhwCGcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=The%20time%20required%20for%20one%20complete%20oscillation%20of%20a%20pendu-%20lum%20is%20called%20its%20period.%20If%20L%20is%20the%20length%20of%20the%20pendu-%20lum%20and%20the%20oscillation%20is%20small%2C%20then%20the%20period%20is%20given%20by%20P%20%3D%202%CF%80%20%3F%20L%20%2F%20g%2C%20where%20g%20is%20the%20constant%20acceleration%20due%20to%20gravity.%20Use%20differentials%20to%20show%20that%20the%20percentage%20error%20in%20P%20is%20approximately%20half%20the%20percentage%20error%20in%20L.&f=false)). The time required for one complete oscillation of a pendulum is called its *period*. If $L$ is the length of the pendulum and the oscillation is small, then the period is given by $P =2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$, where $g$ is the constant acceleration due to gravity. Show that the percentage error in $P$ is approximately half the percentage error in $L$.
  4. **Richter scale** ([Anton's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=n0kzDAAAQBAJ&dq=calculus+early+transcendentals+anton&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEkqb-wZPmAhUxIbkGHSW4AsIQ6AEIPjAC)). The magnitude $R$ of an earthquake on the Richter scale is related to the amplitude $A$ of the shock wave by the equation $R=\log_{10}(\frac{A}{A_0})$, where $A_0$ is a small positive constant. (Originally, $A_0$ was the smallest possible amplitude that could be detected.) Show that for a small change in $A$ the change in $R$ can be approximated by multiplying the relative change $\Delta A/A$ in amplitude by $0.4343$.
  5. The [*small angle approximation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation) ([Anton's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=U2uv84cpJHQC&pg=RA1-PA183&dq=The+local+linear+approximation+sinx+%E2%89%88+x+is+known+as+the+small+angle+approximation+and+has+both+practical+and+theoretical+applications.+Do+some+research+on+some+of+these+applications,+and+write+a+short+report+on+the+results+of+your+investigations.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFgtjixZPmAhXZJbkGHVy6BYwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=The%20local%20linear%20approximation%20sinx%20%E2%89%88%20x%20is%20known%20as%20the%20small%20angle%20approximation%20and%20has%20both%20practical%20and%20theoretical%20applications.%20Do%20some%20research%20on%20some%20of%20these%20applications%2C%20and%20write%20a%20short%20report%20on%20the%20results%20of%20your%20investigations.&f=false)).

Answer (score 0):

Besides Pedro answer, I would add application in control theory. We use control theory in robotics application as instance. The theory is developed for linear systems, but mechanical modeling is very non-linear, therefore, it is necessary use linear approximations for robotics. In the other hand, we can apply non-linear control theory, but is still a foggy path.